# Combining two blocks and looping over both

Tags: python, selenium

Hello sorry for the vague topic post but I am practicing web scraping with selenium.  I have a list of links "urls_to_scrape" and for each url I want to visit the links and extract certain elements I have been able to extract each the elements but now I am confused how to do it for each url in my list.  See code below.

```
urls_to_scrape # list containing urls I want to perform the code below for 
               # each url


results = []

articles = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#MainW article')

counter = 1

for article in articles:
  result = {}
  try:
     title = article.find_element_by_css_selector('a').text
  except: 
     continue

 counter = counter + 1

 excerpt = article.find_element_by_css_selector('div > div > p').text

 author = 
 article.find_element_by_css_selector('div > footer > address > a').text

 date = article.find_element_by_css_selector('div > footer > time').text

 link=
 article.find_element_by_css_selector('div>h2>a').get_attribute('href')

 result['title'] = title
 result['excerpt'] = excerpt
 result['author'] = author
 result['date'] = date
 result['link'] = link

 results.append(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got an indentation issue. Try this:

```
urls_to_scrape # list containing urls I want to perform the code below for 
               # each url


results = []

articles = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#MainW article')

counter = 1

for article in articles:
    result = {}
    try:
        title = article.find_element_by_css_selector('a').text
    except: 
        continue

    counter = counter + 1

    excerpt = article.find_element_by_css_selector('div > div > p').text

    author = article.find_element_by_css_selector('div > footer > address > a').text

    date = article.find_element_by_css_selector('div > footer > time').text

    link = article.find_element_by_css_selector('div>h2>a').get_attribute('href')

    result['title'] = title
    result['excerpt'] = excerpt
    result['author'] = author
    result['date'] = date
    result['link'] = link
    results.append(result)
```

What is `driver` by the way? You haven't provided the line that fetches the URL. This line is critical for fetching multiple URLs as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function that performs scraping (everything below results = []), such as

```
def scrape(url):
    ...
    ...
     return result
```

Then,

```
for url in url_to_scrape:
    result = scrape(url)
    results.append(result)
```

Comment: I am getting first article repeated numerous times when I tried the way you suggested.  @postoronnim